# maintaning drop down selected state after post back in MVC razor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In a MVC 4 Web I have drop-down lists with the below sample code:

```
@(Html.DropDownList("Condition2", new SelectList(Model.Makes, "CCultureId", "CTitle"), "All",new {@class="span3"}))
```

I have All as a first option in select and on button press, page shows data in it. After post back, drop downs got reset on button press, can you please guide me how to make drop down keeping its state even after page post backs (I understand in MVC4 there are no postback, I m reffering it as a round trip to server).

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is, in your controller, return the submitted value in the model. This means your dropdownlist should be hooked up to your viewmodel.

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // more properties...
    public string Make {get;set;}
    // more properties
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // do postback stuff
    return View(model); // model.Make is set to whatever was submitted and will be returned   
}
```

Html:

```
@model Models.MyViewModel

@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make, 
     new SelectList(Model.Makes, "CCultureId", "CTitle", Model.Make), 
     "All", new {@class="span3"}))
```

Comment: thanks @jzm, my model is a little complex and have multiple lists and items in it, it is not a single item. Will your suggestion still maintain the last selected item state in drop down ?

Comment: Yes. Just create a property for the select box like i have e.g. "Make". Then refer to it in your Html.DropDownListFor() statement in your html, then you can return it in your post action.

Comment: do I need to pass same model to view again which is coming as a parameter in action ? actually as per now inside action I m creating a new model and passing it to view. Please advice.

Comment: well instead of creating a new model and passing it to the view, just return the same view that was passed in

Comment: Ok. Try this: 
@(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make, 
     new SelectList(Model.Makes, "CCultureId", "CTitle", Model.Make), 
     "All", new {@class="span3"}))

Comment: This is a very clean solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Old question, but the key for me was to pass the current value with `new SelectList`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewbag to save the selected item, see blew:

**Get Action**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {

        ViewBag.SelectedItem = "";
         ///
        return View(new yourViewModel);
    }
```

**Post Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection form,YourViewModel model)
{
    ViewBag.SelectedItem = form["Condition2"];
     ///
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@(Html.DropDownList("Condition2", new SelectList(Model.Makes, "CCultureId",
 "CTitle",ViewBag.SelectedItem), "All",new {@class="span3"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ? operator which works like this and use the Selected property of the selectlistitem

```
Console.WriteLine((2 == 2 ? "true" : "false"));
```

and then for example

```
private Entities en = new Entities(); 

        public ActionResult Index(string selectedvalue)
                {

    List<SelectListItem> selectlist = 

    en.tblUser.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id, 

    Selected = ( x.Name == selectedvalue ? false : true) })

    .ToList();

                    ViewBag.DropDown = selectlist;
                    return View();
                }
```

then in the view u simply put this

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownName", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDown))
```

obviously its not recommended to use viewbag but instead use a model with a list property.